# How to make ObjectBox support Map?

Tags: android, hashmap, objectbox

```
@Entity
public class AgendaEntity {
    @Id public long id;

    private Map unitMap;


    public Map getUnitMap() {
        return unitMap;
    }

    public void setUnitMap(Map unitMap) {
        this.unitMap = unitMap;
    }
}
```

Causes following error :-

```
error: [ObjectBox] Field type "java.util.Map" is not supported. Consider making the target an @Entity, or using @Convert or @Transient on the field (see docs).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot avoid a map (e.g. do you have a fixed amount of entries?), write a converter for your map, see [custom types docs](http://objectbox.io/documentation/custom-types/) for details.

Example:

```
@Convert(converter = MyUnitConverter.class, dbType = String.class)
private Map unitMap;
```

MyUnitConverter has to be implemented by you.